# Cannot install chocolatey module on Windows (certificate error?)

Tags: certificate, puppet

I'm trying to use Puppet to install .NET on Windows. I'm using the `rismoney-chocolatey` module. However when I try to install this module:

`puppet module install rismoney-chocolatey`

I get the following error:

```
[mNotice: Preparing to install into C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/modules ...[0m
[mNotice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...[0m
Failed to add /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Failed to add /C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Durbanville/O=Thawte/OU=Thawte Certification/CN=Thawte Timestamping CA
Failed to add /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011
Failed to add /C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II
Failed to add /C=DE/ST=Hamburg/L=Hamburg/O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA/emailAddress=certificate@trustcenter.de
Failed to add /C=DE/ST=Hamburg/L=Hamburg/O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA/emailAddress=certificate@trustcenter.de
Failed to add /C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Universal CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Universal CA I
Failed to add /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
Failed to add /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Failed to add /C=ZA/ST=Western Cape/L=Durbanville/O=Thawte/OU=Thawte Certification/CN=Thawte Timestamping CA
Failed to add /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011
Failed to add /C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II
Failed to add /C=DE/ST=Hamburg/L=Hamburg/O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 3 CA/emailAddress=certificate@trustcenter.de
Failed to add /C=DE/ST=Hamburg/L=Hamburg/O=TC TrustCenter for Security in Data Networks GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA/emailAddress=certificate@trustcenter.de
Failed to add /C=DE/O=TC TrustCenter GmbH/OU=TC TrustCenter Universal CA/CN=TC TrustCenter Universal CA I
Failed to add /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
[mNotice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...[0m
C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/modules
└── rismoney-chocolatey ([0;36mv0.0.3[0m)
```

This module then cannot be used - if I attempt to apply a puppet script which uses it, I get the following error:

```
package { 'DotNet4.5':
    ensure          => installed,
    provider        => 'chocolatey',
}
```

Gives:

`Error: /Package[DotNet4.5]: Provider chocolatey is not functional on this host`

(I have tried installing the GeoTrust CA certificate as described in the [troubleshooting documents](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/troubleshooting.html#error-messages), but that doesn't fix the issue).

Comment: There is now a supported `puppetlabs/chocolatey` module. See https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

It seems that the `rismoney-chocolatey` modules doesn't currently (at time of asking/answering) actually install chocolatey.

So the fix is to install chocolatey by some other means.

Reference: https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey/issues/28

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the solution was to use the "official" chocolatey package via the following:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "puppet module install chocolatey-chocolatey"
```

The project where I use this is here: https://github.com/Catharz/win-ruby-dev

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while, but now the Chocolatey provider lives at https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey and you can see we support ensuring Chocolatey itself is installed with

```
include chocolatey
```

We also have business friendly internal options available so one doesn't need to hit the internet to do so.

```
class {'chocolatey':
  chocolatey_download_url => 'https://internalurl/to/chocolatey.nupkg',
  use_7zip                => false,
  choco_install_timeout   => 2700,
}
```

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#usage